# AWS Amplify. Use existing resources

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I have followed the tutorial:

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start?ref=amplify-android-btn

To integrate AWS S3 with my android application.

I'm able to download a file, and everything works fine.

I've notice that when i create a enviroment, it creates a new bucket, i don't want to create a new bucket, i want to use an existing one.

I've tried to change the bucket in the `awsconfiguration.json`. But it does not work.

```
"S3TransferUtility": {
    "Default": {
        "Bucket": "somebucket",
        "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
}
```

```
AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: <ID>)
```

I don't want to create a new bucket, i want to be able to access crated buckets that share objects across other apps.

Comment: What did you do to fix `AccessDenied` on the 'existing bucket' How did you test that with the correct credentials, you can access that bucket.

Comment: I'm currently using `User GUEST` to download the file from the created butcket.

Comment: Please review: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/ and also that the AWS Amplify demo you linked uses AWS Cognito for user management. You would need to get Cognito to access the 'existing bucket', but that involved tutorials on IAM policies. See: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/storage#storage-access

Comment: Hey @MorrisonChang, i checked the links you provided, i have created an user in Cognito. I login first before trying to download the file. Once my user is logged in i try to download the file, but it stills returning 403. My question is, how to give the user access to download, or what user do i have to login with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved. For anyone who is interested in.

For using an existing bucket, without creating a environment with amplify. The only thing i done was to add manually the file `awsconfiguration.json` inside the `raw` folder. I do not use amplify.

So, my `awsconfiguration.json` looks like:

```
{
"Version": "1.0",
"IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
},
"CredentialsProvider": {
    "CognitoIdentity": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "cognito-pool-id",
            "Region": "region"
        }
    }
},
"S3TransferUtility": {
    "Default": {
        "Bucket": "somebucket",
        "Region": "region"
    }
}
}
```

And to download objects from S3 i make my `TransferUtility` like this:

```
val transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
        .context(context)
        .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().configuration)
        .s3Client(getAmazonS3Client())
        .build()

private fun getAmazonS3Client(): AmazonS3Client{
    if (amazonS3Client == null) {
        amazonS3Client = AmazonS3Client(
                CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    context, 
                    BuildConfig.S3_POOL_ID, 
                    Regions.US_EAST_2
                ),
                Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
                )
    }

    return amazonS3Client!!
}
```